# Calling Javascript anonymous function method on timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval, anonymous-function

I'm working on creating a fireworks show in javascript for my last day of work tomorrow and I'm having some trouble getting it to automate. I'm using the fireworks found [here](http://creativejs.com/tutorials/creating-fireworks/) and it works great, but this is going to be on a status webpage that I developed a while ago so I want the fireworks to be automatic instead of on click.

I've created a function on the fireworks.js page that looks like this...

```
function fireFireworks(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        createFirework();
    }
}
```

This will be used to fire between 1 and 3 fireworks when it's called. Then I setup

```
setInterval('fireFireworks()', 5000);
```

When both of these are defined in my local file and not in the fireworks.js file I get a bad reference to `createFirework()`.

So I moved the `fireFireworks()` to just under the initialize function in fireworks.js and then I would get a bad reference to `fireFireworks()` so I moved my `setInterval` into the `intialize` function, but I still get a bad reference to `fireFireworks()`.

However, if I change the binder for `onmouseup` from 
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', createFireworks, true);
to
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', fireFireworks, true);

It successfully creates my multiple fireworks.

I'm assuming that the scope of setInterval is playing a part here. If anyone could give me an idea of how I could automate this as well as some info as to why my setup isn't working I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you try just `setInterval(fireFireworks, 5000)`?

Comment: Please don't use strings in `setInterval()`, use anonymous functions or just the function name itself: `setInterval(fireFireworks, 5000);`

Comment: @pimvdb, I did once that method was in the fireworks.js file. Still no luck.

Comment: @pimvdb Let me rephrase my last comment, I did not try it as not a string. Now that I have, it works beautifully. Any information as to why the string doesn't work, but it does for non anonymous functions?

Comment: Please provide more code. I would like to see how and where you are calling your functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nicer to pass the function itself to `setInterval`, i.e.

```
setInterval (fireFireworks, 5000)
```

As for the scoping, if your `createFireworks` function isn't used anywhere else, just put it *inside* `fireFireworks` and you don't have to worry about it any more (it's generally considered nicer to do that anyway, because it avoids polluting the global scope).

Otherwise, wrap both functions in a closure:

```
(function ()
{
    function fireFireworks ()
    {
        /* ... */
    }

    function createFirework ()
    {
        /* ... */
    }

    setInterval (fireFireworks, 5000)

}) ();
```

Comment: Interesting that passing the function as a string works in a general case but not when closures are involved.

Comment: That's because the string is evaluated later, in global scope. The name of your function only means anything inside the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function(global){
    var theShow = {},
        createFirework;

    createFirework = function() {
    };    

    theShow.fireFireworks = function() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1,
            i = 0;
        for(i;i<num;i++){
            createFirework();
        }
    };
   global.setInterval(theShow.fireFireworks , 5000);
   global.theShow = theShow;
}(window));
```

You will now be able to call `theShow.firFireworks()` from any JavaScript code in your application as long at it is after this code is called. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the setInterval() function in way that is messing up your scope, (using a string).  Try adding to your initialize function:

```
 var fireworksTimer = setInterval(fireFireworks, 5000);
```

then if you make fireFireworks a "public" function,

```
 fireFireworks = function(){
      ....
 }
```

in the separate js file, it should now be callable.

Comment: accidental submission. Holy fast down vote, sorry, hit tab then space, which = submit in SO.

Comment: Well, actually the downvote is for something else: it's not *wrong* to put a string in `setInterval`, it's just very ugly.

Answer (score -1):

setInterval('fireFireworks', 20) will not work because it is a string u should type setInterval(fireFireworks,20) this will work now

Comment: Why answer something from 9 years ago that already has an accepted answer?

Comment: I didn't knew it is 9 years old